# When we click on Button it Should generate a PDF FORM with the Ship to and Ship from details

Tags: visualforce, javascript, custom-button, standardcontroller

Can anyone help me out with this requirement ?Any help is much appreciated.

We do have two Buttons as GeneratePicklist and GenerateInvoice created using Execute Javascript ,ON a detail page button.

**The requirement is :when we click on the Button ,it should generate a PDF form with the ship to and from address details.**
But we get an Error as :Visualforce Error List index out of bounds: 0 and the pdf form is not getting generated.

**Button formula :**

```
window.open("{!IF(ISPICKVAL(Opportunity.StageName,"LV Stock Available"), 
"https://c.cs10.visual.force.com/apex/InvoiceReportUS?id="+Opportunity.Id, 
"https://c.cs10.visual.force.com/apex/InvoiceReport?id="+Opportunity.Id)}",'_Blank')
```

VF Page :

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" renderAs="pdf" applyhtmltag="false" showHeader="false" applyBodyTag="false" extensions="InvoiceController">
<head>
    <style>
        @page {
            margin: 1px 50px 225px 50px; 
            size:A4;
            Padding-top:30px;

            @top-center { 
                    content : element(header);
                 }

            @bottom-center {
                    content : element(footer);
                    height:200px;
                    padding-top:10px;
                 }
        } 
        body { font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS'; }
        .companyName { font: bold 30px; color: red; }  
        table {width:100%; border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; border-width: 1px; border-color:#C0C0C0;border-style:solid;} 
        .header-table-data { border-width: 1px; border-color:Black;border-style:solid;background-color:#FFFFFF;
                             color:Black; font-size:14px; font-family:Verdana;
                             text-align:center;}
        .header-table-heading {border-width: 1px; border-color:Black;border-style:solid;background-color:#C0C0C0; 
                               font-weight:bold;color:Black; font-size:14px; font-family:Verdana;
                               text-align:center;}
        .header-data { border-width: 0px; border-color:Black;border-style:solid;background-color:#FFFFFF;
                       color:Black; font-size:14px; font-family:Verdana;text-align:left; padding-right: 10px;}

        .header-heading {border-width: 0px; border-color:Black;border-style:solid; 
                         font-weight:bold;color:Black; font-size:14px; font-family:Verdana;
                         text-align:left;}
    </style>

</head>
<body> 

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><img style="WIDTH:25%; HEIGHT: 25%" src='{!URLFOR($Resource.Bridgelux_New_Logo)}' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <br/>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Commercial Invoice</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table><br/>

    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0" >
        <tr>
           <!--- <td border="0" bgcolor="Silver">Sold To</td> ---->
            <td bgcolor="Silver">Ship To:</td>
            <td bgcolor="Silver">Ship From</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <!--<td style="border-width: 0px; border-color:Black;border-style:solid;background-color:#FFFFFF;" align="left" width="10%">
                <f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">
                    <!-- Code starts here ********************************************************* -->
                    <!-- {!showaddressonVf} -->
                   <!-- <apex:outputText value="{!opportunity.account.Name}"></apex:outputText><br/>-->
                    <!-- Added by Sumit -->
                   <!-- <apex:outputText value=" {!all}" escape="false"></apex:outputText>-->
                    <!--     -----------   -->
                    <!--<br />-->
                <!--</f>-->
            <!--</td> -->     
            <td style="border-width: 0px; border-color:Black;border-style:solid;background-color:#FFFFFF;" align="left" width="10%">
            <f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">
                <!-- Code starts here ********************************************************* -->
                <!-- Added below line by KiranmaiKosaraju. To show Ship To Account Name If diff from Account Name or else show Account Name -->
                <apex:outputText value="{!IF ((opportunity.Ship_To_Account_Name__c = NULL),  opportunity.account.Name,opportunity.Ship_To_Account_Name__c)}"></apex:outputText><br /> 
                <!--<apex:outputText value="{!opportunity.account.Name}"></apex:outputText><br /> -->
                <!-- Added by Sumit -->
                <apex:outputText value=" {!all}" escape="false"></apex:outputText>
                <!--     -----------   -->
                <br />  
            </f>
            </td>
            <td style="border-width: 0px; border-color:Black;border-style:solid;background-color:#FFFFFF;" align="left" width="10%">
            <f style="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana;">
                Bridgelux Inc. C/O JSI Logistics (HK) Ltd.<br/>
                16/F Tsuen Wan International Center,<br/>
                68 Wang Lung Street, Tsuen Wan,<br/>
                Hong Kong<br/>
                Tel: (852) 3761 7080<br/>
                Fax: (852) 2750 0721<br/>
            </f>
            <f style="color:Blue; font-size:12px; font-family:Tahoma;"> Email:Info@bridgelux.com</f>
            <f style="color:Blue; font-size:10px; font-family:Trebuchet MS;"><br/> </f>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table> 

     <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" width="100%" >
        <tr>
             <td class="header-heading">
                Ship Date:
             </td>
             <td class="header-data">
                <apex:outputText value="{!opportunity.Sys_today_s_date__c}"></apex:outputText><br/>
             </td>
             <td class="header-heading">
                Special Instructions:
             </td>
             <td class="header-data">                
                <apex:outputText value="{!opportunity.Special_Instructions__c}"></apex:outputText>
             </td>
        </tr>
    </table> 

     <table>
        <tr border="0">
            <td class="header-table-heading">CI Invoice Id</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Ship Date<b/></td>
            <!----<td class="header-table-heading">Sales Order#</td>--->
            <td class="header-table-heading">Opportunity Name<b/></td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Order Date</td>
            <!---<td class="header-table-heading">Customer#</td>--->
            <td class="header-table-heading">Customer Name</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Salesorder_number__c}"></apex:outputText></td>
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opportunity.Sys_today_s_date__c}"></apex:outputText></td>
            <!--<td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Salesorder_number__c}"></apex:outputText></td>-->
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Name}"></apex:outputText></td>
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Sys_createddate__c}"></apex:outputText></td>
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opportunity.account.Name}"></apex:outputText></td>
           <!-- <td class="header-table-data">{!Opportunity.account.Ebs_Customer_number__c}</td>-->
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <table >
        <tr>
            <td class="header-table-heading">LN</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Item</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Customer Item #<b/></td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">COO</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">ECCN #</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">UOM</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Unit Price</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Quantity</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Extension</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="header-table-heading"></td>
            <td colspan="8" style="text-align:left"  class="header-table-heading">Description</td>
        </tr>
        <apex:repeat value="{!appointmentList}" var="line">
        <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!if(line.pick==true, true, false)}">

        <tr>         
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!line.LineNumber}"></apex:outputText></td>
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!line.productname}"></apex:outputText></td>
            <td class="header-table-data"></td>
            <td class="header-table-data"></td>
            <td class="header-table-data">8541.40.2000</td>
            <td class="header-table-data">EA</td>
            <td class="header-table-data">$1</td>
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputtext value="{!line.quantity}"></apex:outputtext></td>
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!line.extension}"></apex:outputText></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="header-table-data"></td>

            <td colspan="8" style="text-align:left" class="header-table-data"><b>Scheduled Ship Date:</b>
                        <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}">
                                <apex:param value="{!line.Scheduledshipdate}"/>
                        </apex:outputText> </td>
        </tr>
        </apex:outputPanel>    
        </apex:repeat>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Gross Weight</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Net Weight</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Shipped Via</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Tracking #</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Payment Terms</td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Incoterms </td>
            <td class="header-table-heading">Currency </td>
            <td rowspan="0" class="header-table-heading">Sub Total <br/>Shipping Charges</td>
            <td rowspan="0" class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opportunity.Pick_Total__c}"></apex:outputText>
                 <br/><apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Shipping_Charges__c}"></apex:outputText><br/></td>

        </tr>
        <apex:repeat value="{!appointmentList1}" var="line1">
        </apex:repeat>
        <tr>
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Gross_Weight__c}"></apex:outputText></td>
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Net_weight__c}"></apex:outputText></td>
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Shipped_Via__c}"></apex:outputText></td>
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Bill_of_Lading__c}"> </apex:outputText></td>
            <td class="header-table-data">Net 30</td>
            <td class="header-table-data">EXW</td>
            <td class="header-table-data">USD</td>
            <td rowspan="0" class="header-table-heading"> Total Amount Due</td>
            <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opportunity.Pick_Total__c + opportunity.Shipping_Charges__c}"></apex:outputText></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</apex:page>
```

**Class :**

```
public with sharing class InvoiceController {
           List<wrapperClass> appointmentList {get;set;}
           List<wrapperClass> appointmentList1 {get;set;} 
           public list<string> addaress{get;set;}
           public string address1{get;set;}
           public string address2{get;set;}
           public string address3{get;set;}
           public string address4{get;set;}
           public string address5{get;set;}
           public string address6{get;set;}
           public string address7{get;set;}
           public  String showaddressonVf{get;set;}
           public string wholeaddress{get;set;}
   //Added by sumit
               List<String> stringList ;
               public String all{get;set;}
           //------------
   public InvoiceController(){
   list<opportunity> op=[select id,Shipment_Info__c
   from opportunity where id=:apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id')];
    //opportunity op=[select id,Shipment_Info__c from opportunity where id=:apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id')];
       //---------------------Added by sumit----------------------
       stringList= new List<String>(); 
       if(op.size()>0)
       if(op[0].Shipment_Info__c!=NULL && op[0].Shipment_Info__c!=''){
           List<String> stringList=(op[0].Shipment_Info__c).split(',');
               for(integer i=0;i<stringList.size();i++){
                   all=all+stringList[i]+'<br/>';
               }

           all=all.remove('null');      
        }
      //------------------------------------------------------------
   }
       public Id OppId{get;set;}


       public InvoiceController(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
       oppId=Apexpages.currentPage().getparameters().get('Id');
   }
               public List<wrapperClass> getappointmentList (){
               wrapperClass tempObj ;
               tempObj = new wrapperClass();
               List<wrapperClass> aReList = new List<wrapperClass>(); 
           List<Opportunity> opp=[select id,Name,AccountId from Opportunity where id=:oppid limit 1];
           List<opportunity> Opp1=[select id,name,CreatedDate from opportunity where id=:oppid];
           //Opportunity opp1=[select id,Name,AccountId from Opportunity where id=:oppid limit 1];
           //Opportunity Opp=[select id,name,CreatedDate from opportunity where id=:oppid ];
                          List<OpportunityLineItem> OPplineitem= [SELECT OpportunityId,Quantity,PricebookEntry.Product2.Name,Sys_total_Amount__c,LN__c,Extension__c,ListPrice
                          ,Pick__c,Schedule_Ship_date__c
                          FROM OpportunityLineItem where OpportunityId=:oppId]; 
                          system.debug('HHHHHHHHHH'+OPplineitem.size());

                   for(integer i=0; i < OPplineitem.size(); i++)
                   {
                     tempObj = new wrapperClass();
                     tempObj.productname= OPplineitem[i].PricebookEntry.Product2.Name;
                     tempObj.quantity=OPplineitem[i].Quantity;
                     tempObj.totalamount=OPplineitem[i].Sys_total_Amount__c;
                     tempObj.unitprice=OPplineitem[i].ListPrice;
                     tempobj.extension=OPplineitem[i].Extension__c;
                     tempobj.LineNumber=OPplineitem[i].LN__c;
                     tempobj.Pick= OPplineitem[i].Pick__c;
                     tempobj.ScheduledShipDate = Opplineitem[i].schedule_ship_date__c;

                     if(tempobj!=null){
                        aReList.add(tempObj);
                     }
                    }
           return aReList;
   }
       public List<wrapperClass> getappointmentList1 (){
           wrapperClass tempObj1 ; 
           List<wrapperClass> aReList1 = new List<wrapperClass>();
                   List<Opportunity> opp=[select id,Name,AccountId,Shipment_Info__c,
                    Shipping_Address_Line1__c,
                        Shipping_Address_Line2__c,
                        Shipping_Address_Line3__c,
                        Shipping_City__c,
                        Shipping_State_Province__c,
                        Shipping_Zipcode__c,
                        Shipping_Country__c  
                        from Opportunity where id=:oppid];
           for(integer i=0; i < opp.size(); i++)
           {
             tempObj1 = new wrapperClass();
             tempObj1.billingAddress= opp[i].Shipment_Info__c;
                               }
             aReList1.add(tempObj1);        

             /* Below code commented by Kiranmai as Shipment Info field is split into multiple fields

             //------- Added by Sumit-----------  
             stringList= new List<String>(); 

             if(aReList1[0].billingAddress!=NULL && aReList1[0].billingAddress!=''){
                List<String> stringList=(aReList1[0].billingAddress).split(',');
                for(integer i=0;i<stringList.size();i++){
                   all=all+stringList[i]+'<br/>';
                }
             } */

             all = all + opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line1__c + '<br/>';
             if(opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line2__c!=NULL && opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line2__c!=''){
                 all = all + opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line2__c + '<br/>';
             }

             if(opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line3__c!=NULL && opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line3__c!=''){
                 all = all + opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line3__c + '<br/>';
             } 

             if(opp[0].Shipping_City__c!=NULL && opp[0].Shipping_City__c!=''){
                 all = all + opp[0].Shipping_City__c + '<br/>';
             }

             if(opp[0].Shipping_State_Province__c!=NULL && opp[0].Shipping_State_Province__c!=''){
                 all = all + opp[0].Shipping_State_Province__c + '<br/>';
             }  

             if(opp[0].Shipping_Zipcode__c!=NULL && opp[0].Shipping_Zipcode__c!=''){
                 all = all + opp[0].Shipping_Zipcode__c + '<br/>';
             }

             if(opp[0].Shipping_Country__c!=NULL && opp[0].Shipping_Country__c!=''){
                 all = all + opp[0].Shipping_Country__c + '<br/>';
             }
            /* all = all + opp[0].Shipping_City__c + ', '+opp[0].Shipping_State_Province__c + ' - ' + opp[0].Shipping_Zipcode__c + '<br/>';
             all = all + opp[0].Shipping_Country__c + '<br/>';*/

             all=all.remove('null');

                /*-----------------------------------*/ 
      return aReList1;  
   }
           public class wrapperClass{
           public String productname{get;set;}
           public Decimal Quantity{get;set;}
           public Decimal totalamount{get;set;}                            
           public Decimal unitprice{get;set;}
           public date todaysdate{get;set;}
           public decimal extension{get;set;}
           public string LineNumber{get;set;}
           public string billingAddress{get;set;}
           public string splittedaddress{get;set;}
           public string wholeaddress{get;set;}
           public boolean Pick{get;set;}
           public date ScheduledShipDate{get;set;}
           public wrapperClass(){}                
       }
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Which line are you getting this error? Most likely the id value you are passing is null or empty or there is no matching record for that id.  Try calling the url directly in the browser without using the button and see if you are getting the same error. I would also see what is the value apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id') in the controller

Comment: @Prady:There is no particular line it displays,Tried with the url also it gives the same Error msg as :List index out of bounds:0

Comment: check your debug logs  to give you an idea of where the problem lies. This should atleast show where the error is occuring. Try adding a system.debug statement to see what is coming in id?

Comment: @Prady :I created a record ,i tried with the URL by giving the record id it worked now.Im thankful to everyone for your needful help.